# How to query this query in mysql the second table is the result?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

**im stuck in this area in my database please help**[image: asdfadf]

Comment: Something like ***table pivot***.

Comment: hi i search for this seems like its table pivot can you give some example query for this its ok not the exact answer only hint

Comment: What query have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service. You are expected to try something first, then ask for specific assistance if stuck.